# HHVM FastCGI not working properly - no response

Tags: php, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, fastcgi, hhvm

I'm new to `HHVM` and started to configure it in my `Vagrant` Machine to run as `FastCGI` but when I hit `localhost:9000` in the browser It responses nothing but error

> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

but If I stop service using `sudo service hhvm stop` and run `HHVM` as normal runtime server by using `hhvm -m server -p 9000` and hit the browser with `localhost:9000` URL and it perfects fine,

The below is the configuration data in `/etc/hhvm/server.ini`

```
; php options

pid = /var/run/hhvm/pid

; hhvm specific

hhvm.server.port = 9000
hhvm.server.type = fastcgi
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php
hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
hhvm.repo.central.path = /var/cache/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc
hhvm.server.source_root = /vagrant/www
```

This is from where I got help to set up `FastCGI` https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/basic-usage/proxygen#automatic-service-startup

How can I run it as automatic startup service?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is possible to run `sudo systemctl enable hhvm` ?

Comment: Hi @FelippeDuarte the result comes `sudo: systemctl: command not found` It's a fresh vagrant setup using `ubuntu/trusty64`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser can't connect to a server running in FastCGI mode, as browsers talk HTTP not FastCGI. Instead, you need to set up a web server (e.g. Apache/Nginx) and have that talk with the browser and the FastCGI server.

The document for [running HHVM+FastCGI](https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/advanced-usage/fastCGI) contains instructions for setting this up with both Apache and Nginx.

Comment: Ahh... that might be a solution. Thanks